# Why GNU ld is leaving a hole in memory?

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, linker, compiler-optimization

I am using GNU linker for ppc 32-bit platform.
As I look at the size of "rodata" section and try to tally it against the symbols in that section, I am seeing that there are some memory holes, which are not assigned any symbol, but contribute to the size of the section.

One such hole is seen here

```
ffffc970    00000050 r _ZL10RING_INDEX
ffffcb68    00000020 r _ZZ19p9_pm_check_quiesceE15SPWKUP_SRC_REGS
```

Though the size of symbol is 0x50, there is a gap of about 424 bytes(0xffffcb68 - 0xffffc970 - 0x50)  before the next symbol in memory. Can we explain this gap? Is there a way to prevent such gaps?

Comment: How did you get this output? How did you compile your program?

Comment: This output is from "nm" on the .out, sorted according to the memory range. Compilation is using gcc C++11 compiler.

Comment: I want to know what compiler options do you use, how do you compile, not which compiler do you use.

Comment: compiler options - -std=c++11 -nostdinc++ -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections.

Comment: If it helps, this is from the following project and all the flags could be found at https://github.com/open-power/sbe/blob/master/src/build/img_defs.mk

Comment: Sorry, I will look at this later.

Answer (score 1):

It could be filled with nameless data e.g. string constants. It's hard to give a more precise answer without a reprocase.